# Get optional params in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-dom

I have the path below

```
            <Route path='/All/Profiles/:username?' component={ProfileLookupPage} />
```

In `ProfileLookupPage` component, How can i get all the optional params. Ex. could be `/all/profiles` or `/all/profiles/abc`

Comment: If I understand your question right, you can use `const {username} = useParams()` in your ProfileLookupPage

Comment: Are you using react router? If so, try reading the docs. https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params

Answer (score 0):

Inside Profile ProfileLookupPage.js you can useParams or props.match.params.username

```
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom"


function ProfileLookupPage(props){

const {username}=useParams();
or 
console.log(props.match.params.username,"username")

return {
           <></>
       }

}
```